# Doctrine Query performance

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am pretty new to doctrine and i have a question about DQL performance. I work for a company with a pretty big database and to get the wanted data i have to write queries with multiple JOIN and WHERES.

My question is:

Is it possible to write "better performing" Queries? An example query would be:

```html
             SELECT u
             FROM User u
             JOIN u.tags t
             JOIN u.profile p
             JOIN p.picture pic
             JOIN u.city c
             WHERE p.Finished = 1
             AND pic.Active = 1
             AND u.created < :eDate 
             AND u.finished = :sDate
             AND t = :tag1 OR t = :tag2
             ORDER BY u.name ASC
```

This is just an example of a query. Some are much longer and have much more JOINS.

I googled a little bit, but the best i could fin [5 Doctrine ORM Performance Traps You Should Avoid](https://tideways.io/profiler/blog/5-doctrine-orm-performance-traps-you-should-avoid)

Number 2 on the link says that you should split the Query and fetch each data yourself. Can someone explain how this would look like on the example above?

Also is there anything else i can do with the query that boosts the performance?

Thank you !

Comment: What makes you think that this is a query that is not good performing? Writing surrounding code makes it less maintainable

Comment: Is the amount of pages/controllers (or rather, the access to those) that actually need **all** the above data high enough to warrant a possible refactoring? I assume not every controller / page needs access to the users pics for example?

Answer (score 3):

This is a superbroad question and it won't be possible to answer it "correctly". So this is what you should do when you are concerned about Doctrine performance:

1. Doctrine ORM isn't meant to be used to for reading/manipulating large datasets, it's an "object" manager - so you read/update/delete objects (or a list of objects), but you shouldn't read / update thousands of items at once. Use Doctrine ODM or native SQL for it.

From Doctrine's [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/batch-processing.html): "*An ORM tool is not primarily well-suited for mass inserts, updates or deletions. Every RDBMS has its own, most effective way of dealing with such operations*"

3. No one will be able to tell you where the "edge" is - so the only thing you can do is: Monitor! Log duration, memory usage etc and check whether you have an issue at all or when you get an issue. Additionally this will help you to identify whether Doctrine is part of your issue if you face one.
4. One option we indeed use to avoid too complex joins and not to loose to much performance (especially in hydrating objects with Dotrine) is to use single queries and fill our objects / relations with these results. BUT see point 1 and 2 AND by using such an approach a certain amount of Doctrine's purpose is contradicted.

Summary: Try it, monitor it - and only if you have an issue: check what you can do specifically to tackle your issue.

If you need any help for a "real" issue please come back.